# Textedit HTML source code not triggering javascript

Tags: javascript, html, macos, textedit

Just getting back into coding after a very long break (approx 10 years) so apologies for any incorrect terminology / if this is a basic question.

-Max OS X
-Text Edit
-Google Chrome

Working on a course on Lynda on programming fundamentals. When I type the HTML source code like for like, my version doesn't trigger the .js file, whereas if I c+p the source code from the tutorial file, it does.

Using Textedit as my editor. Very confusing as it is very simple code, and I have copied it identically, but it doesn't react the same way when I type it myself. The rest of the HMTL loads fine but the .js script just doesn't load.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Simple Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>This is a very simple HTML page</p>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I've uploaded the files to mediafire. Container.html is from the tutorial. Container1.html is the HTML file I have typed out myself. Have been scratching my head over this for a while and can't figure out what the difference is between the 2 files except the size (4 bytes).

http://www.mediafire.com/file/p4sz93u9g6admwn/Textedit_JS_Problem.zip

Thanks!

H

Comment: What happens when you type the code in something like http://jsbin.com ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of double quotes in your Container2.html. So its seems the code changes its format from ***UTF*** to a different one. So what you need to is, open your container2.html file, and go to this line

`<script src=“script.js”></script>`

Change it to below by deleting double quotes and typing again:

`<script src="script.js"></script>`

Notice the change in double quote ;)

Comment: Thanks. This didn't solve my problem immediately as the keyboard I have (macbook pro) only has one key for quotation marks. However it did make me realise that problem was the quotation marks and a quick google search reveals that OSX has something called smart quotes (preference > keyboard > text) and this is what was causing the problem, by automatically inserting opening and closing double quotes, rather than just 'normal' ones.

Comment: Oki so that means there was a setting change, as I also use Macbook pro and code almost every day. :)